# How to measure / determine a FET's Vto (Vgs_off)?

Tags: fet, jfet

I have a bunch of FETs and i would like to select them / choose only those with -0.7 Vto. Is it an easy way to measure this parameter?

Thanks

Comment: some circuits here may be of use http://stompville.co.uk/?p=112

Comment: Use a [curve tracer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_curve_tracer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check it functionally- eg. below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0PYkk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the LED lights visibly (maybe tens of uA for an efficient LED) the transistor is not fully off. Typically Vgs(th) may be specified at 250uA so most LEDs will be easily visible in normal room lighting.

Adjust the divider to give whatever safety margin you would like. Keep in mind that Vgs(th) drops with increasing temperature so you may wish to allow for that by reducing the gate test voltage.

If you are using a JFET, obviously the voltage divider would be from a negative voltage (eg. +/-5V with +5 for the LED and -5V for the gate divider).